# How to get a file without the extension in Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm saving images to my resources folder regardless of the extension, and I want to load them the same way. Example: I want to get the image named "foo" whether it is "foo.jpg" or "foo.png".

Right now I'm loading the image for each extension and returning it if it exists OR trying for the next extension if an exception is thrown like so:

```java
    StringBuilder relativePath = new StringBuilder().append("src/main/resources/static/images/").append("/")
                    .append(id).append("/").append(imageName);
    File imageFile = null;
    byte[] imageBytes = null;
    try {
            imageFile = new File(new StringBuilder(relativePath).append(".jpg").toString());
            imageBytes = Files.readAllBytes(imageFile.toPath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    if (imageBytes == null) {
            imageFile = new File(relativePath.append(".png").toString());
            imageBytes = Files.readAllBytes(imageFile.toPath());
        }
```

I feel like it's not the best way to do that, is there a way to load an image by its name and regardless of the extension?

Comment: Please post some relevant code

Comment: Hint: Get a list of files in the folder, then extract the file name using a substring check if it meets your criteria `if(fileName.equals("foo") || fileName.startsWith("foo.")){...}`, then you can load the file using the full path (original name) as normal.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check it the file exists

```
File foo = new File("foo.jpg");
if (!foo.exists) {
  foo = new File("foo.png");
}
```

But if you really want to load without using the extension, then you could list the files in directory that match a given pattern.

```
File dir = new File("/path/to/images/dir/");
File [] files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.matches("foo\\.(jpg|png)");
    }
});

File foo = files[0];
```